# "chrome" in the protocol section of a URL

Tags: protocols

What does the following mean? I assume `chrome` refers to Google's webbrowser [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), but does it have its own special protocol (like http:// and ftp://)?

```
<iframe src="chrome://extension/content/web/web.htm" />"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't; `chrome://` is a cue to what's known as a **protocol handler**. Basically, protocol handlers register a protocol scheme, and the browser will then pass off URLs matching that scheme to the handler.

One example of this functionality that you're probably familiar with is `mailto:`, which is not a protocol, but merely informs the browser to hand off the subsequent URI to a mail program.

Answer (score 7):

It has several meanings - [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome)

This is probably what you're looking for:

> **A chrome:// URL**
>   An URL using the chrome:// protocol. Code loaded from a chrome URL has extended, or chrome,privileges. XUL-based applications load the code for their interface from chrome:// URLs.
>
> **Chrome privileges**
>   The code running with chrome privileges is allowed to do everything, unlike the web content, which is restricted in several ways.

Comment: Most correct answer. To make it explicit: The "chrome:" URLs have nothing to do with Google Chrome. Both of these two meanings are Mozilla-specific, and that's also where I think the "chrome:" URLs originated.

Answer (score 3):

It's a special scheme used to refer to something inside the browser itself, or an add-on. There's probably no protocol per se, it just causes Chrome to access an internal resource in some way.

Also, "chrome" probably refers to "the stuff around the page" (i.e. the browser UI) rather than Google Chrome, although it is also what Google Chrome is named after. Firefox uses the same scheme for its internal things.

Comment: And Firefox used it before Chrome Browser :) It also refers to privileged code, that isn't within the web-page.